# Best approach for a singleton/reusable Server object in Node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, singleton

Whats a "good" approach if I want to instantiate an Express server at application start time, and later reference some of the the instantiated server's properties in another class? Seems like a singleton server instance would work, but that just feels wrong in JS/node.

For instance:

```
# app.coffee 
server = new Server()

# server.coffee
Http = require 'http'
express = require 'express'

class Server
  foos: null

  constructor: ->
    @app = express()
    Http.createServer(@app).listen('1337', 'localhost', cb)

  cb: ->
    @foos = ['foo', 'bar']


# another_class.coffee
Server = require './server'

class AnotherClass
  constructor: ->
    # how do I access and do something with the instantiated server object in app.coffee
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to define a singleton for coffeescript is to create a variable usable throughout the whole code.

Here is an example program I have written:

```
class TestHandler
    constuctor: (@elementHandler) ->

    testList: []

    addTest: (test) ->
      @testList.push test

    getTestList: ->
      @testList

    getTestForName: (name) ->
      for e in @getTestList() when e.getName() is name
        return e

    updateTestName: (name, newName) ->
      @getTestForName(name).name = newName

class Test
  constructor: (name) ->
    @name = name

  getName: ->
    @name

testHandler = new TestHandler()
testHandler.addTest new Test 'hi'
```

As you can see, at the vary bottom outside of the `class` scope I create a variable with a new instance of `TestHandler`.  I then can use `testHandler` inside any of my classes an it will always link to that specific one.